# Manage ImageIcon in jPanel

Tags: swing, jlabel, imageicon

I have a problem when loading a image using jLabel to Imageicon  into a Jpanel. When The image have big size (width and height), it makes a Jpanel in my Splitpane so big too in display. How to make this image have default size?

And, how to implement mouse or mouse wheel when big size image is loaded. So ,It makes the image can be dragged or pull up and down... ?

My code like this...

```
public FileImage() {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("/media/Data/workspace/final_tugas_akhir/tmp/hasil/akhirnya.png"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Failed to Load Image...!!! ");
    }

    JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    jLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
    jPanel3.add(jLabel); // jpanel3 is my panel in main class

}
```

and in main class just use this

```
pnlProsesAlgoritma.add(new FileImage()); //  pnlProsesAlgoritma is panel to "stick" jpanel3
```

this is my screenchot before image not yet loaded :https://www.dropbox.com/s/euslx1jj3n21x7j/before.png

after the image loaded looked like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/0mghkg0bs5cmo9d/after.png

P.S : I am using splitPanel to separate two panel. When the image is loaded, the other panel is shifted...
Thanks 4 the help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/). It will automatically resize itself to fill the space available.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your `JPanel` inside a [**`JScrollPane`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html).

This way, your sizing problem will be solved, and you can navigate large image easily too.